# $G$-invariant endomorphisms and representations of $SO(n)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

For $n\geq 3$ I want to show that the representation  of $SO(n)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ given my matrix multiplication is irreducible.
$$ \pi(g)v=g\cdot v$$.

Since this representation is finite, it is uniterizable. Therefore by Schurs   lemma we need only show that $\text{End}_G({\mathbb C}^n)$ is given by $\lambda I$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb C $.

Now an element $A$ in $\text{End}({\mathbb C}^n)$ is given by an $n\times n$ matrix. As far as I understand an element $A$ in $\text{End}_G({\mathbb C}^n)$ is an $A$ such that $A=gAg^{-1}$ for all $g$ in $SO(n)$. I think this is also exactly the centralizer of $SO(n)$.

Questions: 
1) Is what I have done so far correct?
2) If so, how does one see that the centralizer of $SO(n)$ consists of multiplies of the identity?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ associated to the eigenvector $x$, we have $A(x)=cx$. For every $B\in SO(n)$, $AB(x)=B(A(x))=cB(x)$ implies that $B(x)$ is an eigenvector of $A$. There exists $B_1,...,B_n$ such that $B_1(x),...,B_n(x)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, we deduce that $A=cI$.

Comment: Do you mean that $B(x)$ is an eigenvector of $A$? I don't see why it follows from $B_1(x),...,B_n(x)$ is a basis of $\mathbb C^n$ that $A=cI$?